# Prove that the given statements are true/false

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let *S* and *T* be non-empty, bounded sets of real numbers and suppose that *s* < *t* for $\forall$*s* $\in$ S and $\forall$*t* $\in$ T

Which of the following statements are true:

(i) inf S $\leq$ inf T

(ii) inf S $\leq$ sup T

(iii) sup S $\leq$ sup T

(iv) sup S $\leq$ inf T

So far I have:

(i) inf S $\implies$ inf S $\leq$ *x* for all *x* $\in$ S

Since *s* < *t* for $\forall$*s* $\in$ S and $\forall$*t* $\in$ T, this implies that inf S $\leq$ *x* for all *x* $\in$ T therefore inf S is a lower bound for T.

inf T means that if *k* is another lower bound for T then *k* $\leq$ inf T.

Let *k* = inf S (since both are lower bounds for T) therefore inf S $\leq$ inf T

(ii) sup T $\implies$ sup T $\geq$ *x* for all *x* $\in$ T

*s* < *t* for $\forall$*s* $\in$ S and $\forall$*t* $\in$ T $\implies$ sup T is a an upper bound for S

Since inf S $\implies$ inf S $\leq$ for all *x* $\in$ S, this implies that inf S $\leq$ sup T

Is that going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Since every $t\in T$ is an upper bound of $S$ and since $\sup S$ is the least upper bound of $S$, $\sup S\leqslant t$, for each $t\in T$. But then, by a simliar argument, $\sup S\leqslant\inf T$.

And now, since $\inf S\leqslant\sup S$, $\inf S\leqslant\inf T$ too.

By a similar argument, $\sup S\leqslant\sup T$.

And now, of course we have that $\inf S\leqslant\sup T$.

Comment: Quick and dirty. Maybe you should make it less dirty. The sets are no empty, in your proof you did not reference to this.